# "if not case" for enums in Swift

Tags: swift

Is there a way to invert `case .A = enumValue` and make it something like `enumValue != .A`?

```
enum MyEnum {
    case A
    case B
    case C
    case D(something: OtherEnum)
}

let enumValue: MyEnum = ...
let otherValue: String = ...

if case .A = enumValue {
    // Do nothing
} else {
    if otherValue == "something" {
        // Do stuff...
    } else {
        // Do other stuff...
    }
}

// More code...
```

I'm trying to remove the empty if-block and reduce the number of lines, so I'm not looking for something like

```
var condition1 = true
if case .A = enumValue {
    condition1 = false
}

if condition1 {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Cant you do this? `if enumValue != MyEnum.A {
    //do
}`

Comment: @Santosh The enumeration can be inferred: if enumValue != .A { //do }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Equatable

First of all you need to make you enum `Equatable`

```
enum MyEnum: Equatable {
    case A
    case B
    case C
    case D(something: OtherEnum)
}
func ==(left:MyEnum, right:MyEnum) -> Bool {
    return true // replace this with your own logic
}
```

### Guard

Now your scenario is a perfect fit tor the `Guard` statement

```
func foo() {
    guard enumValue != .A else { return }

    if otherValue == "something" {
        // Do stuff...
    } else {
        // Do other stuff...
    }
}
```

In the code above, if `enumValue != .A` then the code flow does continue.
Otherwise (when `enumValue == .A`) the execution stops and `{ return }` is executed.

Comment: Thanks. I already implemented the "==" operator, but I didn't know I had to add ": Equatable". Seems redundant.

Comment: It is not redundant as the compiler knows that you implement a protocol by explicitly declaring conformance. Otherwise it won't check if you have implemented the required methods.